# Steam a Youtube video using youtube-dl but not using the best quality

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I want to stream a video using youtube-dl but I don't want to stream the best quality. I want it to stream using DASH, with the variable stream quality. Is it possible to do that using youtube-dl?

Comment: Your question seems a bit confusing. On the title you mention "download" but on the body you talk about stream with DASH.

Comment: Sorry for that. I actually meant stream via DASH. I'll fix it now. Thanks.